# JavaScript match access_token in source page

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this input string for a regular expression

```
ine",monitor_crashes:false,container_type:null,min_aspect_ratio:0.25,max_aspect_ratio:4,number_of_partitions:2,multi_partitioning_enabled:false,access_token:"EAAAAUaZA8jlABAOZC1TJwwFgfHyWt4V6b6B6cNxMXKkrjcpmzYS2vB7GWnIJFZCFQMPPEoZCInyJVigwcn8DtZA9xtYNATZBZBriOZBjAhdZCMfZCwohKOISSpC8aewclxA3U3X2PqPZBwZCdZBcKNA2Ydr2pQECR6ZBbuOaAZD",resumability_enabled:true,resumable_service_override:null,change_default_chunk_size:true,client_chunk_size:200000000,use_real_progress_percentage:false,use_progress_linearity:0,use_progress_transform_x:1,early_receive:false
```

I try to grab access token. But result return not single value.

I want single value:

"EAAAAUaZA8jlABAOZC1TJwwFgfHyWt4V6b6B6cNxMXKkrjcpmzYS2vB7GWnIJFZCFQMPPEoZCInyJVigwcn8DtZA9xtYNATZBZBriOZBjAhdZCMfZCwohKOISSpC8aewclxA3U3X2PqPZBwZCdZBcKNA2Ydr2pQECR6ZBbuOaAZD"

How to improvement my regex.

My test https://www.debuggex.com/r/xPqpBV3e9h2yoghE

My regex: `(\w)+(?="|access_token$)`

Comment: Your question can't be understood! But I think your solution would be closer to JSON.parse than from RegExp...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to ask, but why not use something like this: `access_token:"(\w+)\"`?

Comment: @JonathanLam 

It work. My English is not so good.

Thank you.

Comment: @user9679123 I added a more thorough explanation in the answers. Make sure to accept the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex, `(\w)+(?="|access_token$)`, matches any length (>= 1) of word characters followed either by an `"` or by `access_token$`. I'm really not sure why you would want to have it *followed* by `access_token$`, because the `access_token` comes *before* the text you're looking for.

I don't know why a simple regex like: `access_token:"(\w+)\"` wouldn't work? (the first capturing group is the string) It looks for the string with the key `access_token`.

Then again, as @desoares said in the comments, it's probably best to parse this JSON with a JSON parser, using: `JSON.parse(yourJsonObjectString).access_token`.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression is what would work:

RegEx:  `access_token:"(\w+?)"`

[Click Here to see Screen Capture of Solution using your page "Debuggex.com"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glA3l.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex = ([A-Z]\w+)
```

Reference:
[enter link description here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/d4tMpJqI5qrZV46u)